# How to make a dict from n'th indices of tuples in list

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I'm looking for the dictionary comprehension to do something like the following:

```
>>> my_list = [(1,2,3,4),(5,6,7,8)]
>>> new_dict = dict( *python voodoo* )
>>> print new_dict
{(1,2):'item1',(5,6):'item2'}
```

Comment: What is `item1` and `item2`?

Comment: clearly, they are strings

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want something like the following:

```
d = {x[:2]:'item'+str(i+1) for i, x in enumerate(my_list)}
```

I'm going to break down how this works so it's less "python voodoo" in the future:

Firstly, we want the first two values from each tuple in the list. This is done by **list slicing**: `x[:2]`. This says "give me the first two values of `x`".

Secondly, utilize `enumerate`, which effectively zips our return values with a 0-based index. For example, if we called `enumerate` on the original list:

```
>>> for enum in enumerate(my_list): 
        print(enum)

(0, (1, 2, 3, 4))
(1, (5, 6, 7, 8))
```

This gives us back a `tuple` with an index as the first element and whatever was in the list in the second element.

We can unpack a two element tuple by assigning it to two values:

```
>>> for i, x in enumerate(my_list):
        print(str(i) + " : " + str(x))

0 : (1, 2, 3, 4)
1 : (5, 6, 7, 8)
```

Finally, all we need to do is put this all into a **dictionary comprehension** (which is very similar to a list comprehension), and do some string conversions.